# c# format data saving to an excel file

Tags: c#, excel, kinect

I am working with the Kinect and trying to save tracking coordinates into an excel file. I have managed to create the excel file and save the data, but i need to format the way in which the data is saved in order to create graphs. How do I do it?

The data is currently displayed in one cell as:

23-04-13 10:24

Head: X:411 Y:255

ShoulderCenter: X:417 Y:317

ShoulderLeft: X:360 Y:353

ShoulderRight: X:474 Y:357

ElbowLeft: X:341 Y:412

ElbowRight: X:513 Y:426

WristLeft: X:321 Y:451

WristRight: X:513 Y:471

HandLeft: X:312 Y:454

HandRight: X:502 Y:471

Spine: X:422 Y:389

HipCenter: X:422 Y:403

HipLeft: X:397 Y:429

HipRight: X:450 Y:434

KneeLeft: X:305 Y:484

KneeRight: X:316 Y:425

AnkleLeft: X:205 Y:547

AnkleRight: X:426 Y:437

FootLeft: X:178 Y:559

FootRight: X:394 Y:441

I need to have the coordinate values in separate cells.

My code for saving to excel.

}

```
        TextBox1.Text = Head;
        TextBox2.Text = ShoulderCenter;
        TextBox3.Text = ShoulderLeft;
        TextBox4.Text = ShoulderRight;
        TextBox5.Text = ElbowLeft;
        TextBox6.Text = ElbowRight;
        TextBox7.Text = WristLeft;
        TextBox8.Text = WristRight;
        TextBox9.Text = HandLeft;
        TextBox10.Text = HandRight;
        TextBox11.Text = Spine;
        TextBox12.Text = HipCenter;
        TextBox13.Text = HipLeft;
        TextBox14.Text = HipRight;
        TextBox15.Text = KneeLeft;
        TextBox16.Text = KneeRight;
        TextBox17.Text = AnkleLeft;
        TextBox18.Text = AnkleRight;
        TextBox19.Text = FootLeft;
        TextBox20.Text = FootRight;


        {
            StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("Data.xls");
            sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
            sw.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(TextBox2.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(TextBox3.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(TextBox4.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(TextBox5.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(TextBox6.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(TextBox7.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(TextBox8.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(TextBox9.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(TextBox10.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(TextBox11.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(TextBox12.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(TextBox13.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(TextBox14.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(TextBox15.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(TextBox16.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(TextBox17.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(TextBox18.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(TextBox19.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(TextBox20.Text);

            sw.Close();          

    }
```

Comment: You're not writing to an xls spreadsheet - you are appending data to a text file that happens to have the .xls extension

Comment: oh, if i write to a text file is it possible to format how the text is displayed within the sw.WriteLine(); as i should be able to import the text file to excel

Comment: if you add commas between the numbers then Excel should put those numbers in individual cells. you could use something like `string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3}", value1, value2, value3, value4)` to format your output

Answer (score 0):

First of all, put your Values in a Array (IEnumerable, List, or what else), so you can go through it with a Loop.

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

And using:

```
public void doExcel()
{

    Excel.Application myExcelApplication = new Excel.Application();
    myExcelApplication.Visible = true; 
    myExcelApplication.ScreenUpdating = true;
    Excel.Workbook myExcelWorkbook = (Excel.Workbook) myExcelApplication.Workbooks.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value)); 
    Excel.Worksheet myExcelWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)myExcelWorkbook.ActiveSheet;

    for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
    {
        myExcelWorkSheet.Cells[3, i] = String.Format("{0}", myList[i]);                
    }
    myExcelWorkbook.Close(true, "C:\\data.xls", System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
}
```